# Map graph with subsets and coordinates

Tags: r

I want to get map that looks similar to:

[image]

I have a dataset of trips, with pickup and drop-off coordinates, and one dummy variable for Hotel destinations and another for Residential destinations. I want to graph a "google" like map with red dots for the location of hotel destinations and blue dots for residential destinations.

```
head(X$pickup_longitude)
[1] -73.78381 -73.77659 -73.77670 -73.78991 -73.78944 -73.79015

head(X$pickup_latitude)
[1] 40.64866 40.64492 40.64538 40.64677 40.64737 40.64415

map <- get_map(location = 'New York City', zoom = 11)
mapPoints <- ggmap(map) + 
geom_point(data=subset(X,Hotel!=0),aes(x=X$dropoff_longitude,y=X$dropoff_latitude, color = "red"))) +
geom_point(data=subset(X,Residential!=0),aes(x=X$dropoff_longitude, y=X$dropoff_latitude, color = "blue")))
```

Which leads to

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (152): x, y, colour
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have used too many parentheses at the geom_point statements.

```
map <- get_map(location="New York City", zoom = 11)

mapPoints <- ggmap(map)+ 
  geom_point(data=X, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, color = "red")) +
  geom_point(data=Y, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, color = "blue"))
```

Comment: Hi, I get the following error: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (85): x, y, colour